# Insert space in gwt using the safe html template

Tags: html, gwt

I have the following gwt html template in order to set the title of a panel in my project.

```
@Template("<div>{0}<span style=\"font-size: 11px;\">{1}</span></div>")
 SafeHtml method1(String title,String subtitle);
```

If title="Hello" and subtitle= "World" for example then the output text of this above format is ->
          HelloWorld

> I want the output of the above format to be as a space between "Hello"
>   and "World" ->
>             Hello World
>
> How to insert a space between the above div as we use '&nbsp' in HTML ?
>
> As this is a template to print the title dynamically I cannot use css
>   for this title. I tried using `&amp;` however it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `&nbsp;` doesn't work, you could add `padding-left: 5px` to your style on the span.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say you can't use css for the title.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the following work? (i.e. inserting a space after `{0}`)

```
@Template("<div>{0} <span style=\"font-size: 11px;\">{1}</span></div>")
SafeHtml method1(String title,String subtitle);
```

Or you could use a `&nbsp;`:

```
@Template("<div>{0}&nbsp;<span style=\"font-size: 11px;\">{1}</span></div>")
SafeHtml method1(String title,String subtitle);
```